# How to determine the number of terms of a summation for a given expression

Tags: summation

Suppose I have a potential as form
$$
V(r)=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{K}a_k r^k}{\sum_{m=0}^{M}b_m r^m} \tag{1}
$$
How can I match the given potential 
$$
V(r)=\frac{-Z}{r}+\alpha r+\beta r^2 \tag{2}
$$
with equation (1)? I mean how can I find the values of K and M for equation (2)?

(They were obtained 3 and 1 for K and M respectively in a reference but I don't understand HOW?!!)

Comment: What is $a_k$ defined as?

Comment: @AlexR. It's just an arbitrary coefficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider
\begin{align*}
V(r)=\frac{-Z+\alpha r^2+\beta r^3}{r}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, So the terms with K=1 and M=0 have been vanished?

Comment: @Wisdom: This is just (2) written with common denominator. Now you can compare the polynomials of numerator and denominator of (1) and (2).

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Wisdom: You're welcome.